# How to use the Delta Method to find $\sqrt{X}$ if $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}(\lambda, \lambda)$ for $\lambda$ large. I am trying to find the approximation by the Delta method of $\sqrt{X}$. The result I saw from my book is that it is $\sqrt{X} \approx \mathcal{N}\left (\sqrt{\lambda}, \frac{1}{4}\right)$. However, the Delta Method requires working with a sequence $X_n$. In this case, it is correct to define the sequence as $X_n = X$ for all $n$? What is the correct way to construct a sequence so that we may use the Delta Method?

Comment: $\sqrt{\lambda}(\frac {X_{\lambda}} {\lambda}-1)\overset{d}\to N(0,1)$ as $\lambda\to \infty$ (think of $\lambda$ as $n$)

Comment: So we do not need to explicitly specify what $X_\lambda$ is here? Is this because we already know that $X$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}(\lambda, \lambda)$ for $\lambda$ large?

Comment: Yes, you are using only asymptotic properties of $X_\lambda$ - not its details. But the details, naturally, do matter (a lot) if you need to determine *how good of an approximation* you are making for finite $\lambda$. Also note that for finite $\lambda$ normal approximation is good only not too far away from the mean. It's very poor (in relative terms) in the tail as Poisson is heavier than normal.

Comment: Got it, thank you!!!!!